# Kafka Connect Microsoft SQL Server Connector is Not giving any result

Tags: sql-server, apache-kafka, confluent-platform, cdc

To run the cdc kafka connect on my local ubuntu machine, I am running it through stand alone Confluent setup.

For Kafka Connect Microsoft SQL Server Connector,

Configuration ,
kafka-connect-mssql.json

```
{
  "name" : "msSqlSourceConnector2",
  "config" : {
    "connector.class" : "io.confluent.connect.cdc.mssql.MsSqlSourceConnector",
    "tasks.max" : "1",
    "initial.database" : "MyDB",
    "username" : "SYS",
    "password" : "Mysql@123",
    "server.name" : "localhost",
    "server.port" : "1433",
    "topics": "MsSql"
  }
}
```

Running below command for starting the producer,

```
./bin/confluent load msSqlSourceConnector2 -d <path>/kafka-connect-mssql.json
```

Getting below result,

```
CLI is intended for development only, not for production
https://docs.confluent.io/current/cli/index.html

{
  "name": "msSqlSourceConnector2",
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.cdc.mssql.MsSqlSourceConnector",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "initial.database": "MyDB",
    "username": "SYS",
    "password": "Mysql@123",
    "server.name": "localhost",
    "server.port": "1433",
    "topics": "MsSql",
    "name": "msSqlSourceConnector2"
  },
  "tasks": [],
  "type": null
}
```

## When I am running consumer, it is not showing any results on it,

```
./bin/kafka-console-consumer --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --from-beginning --property print.key=true --topic MsSql
```

On Ms - sql side when I am doing insert,update and delete it is capturing the changes in respective CDC tables.

Let me know if anyone play with this connector any time.

Comment: You meant to say it is **not** capturing? Have you looked at `confluent logs connect`? Also Mysql@123 seems like an odd password for mssql (it's not mysql)

Comment: @cricket_007, Yes it is not giving me any result. Password is correct :) .

Comment: @cricket_007, Any thoughts ?

Comment: I'm not sure. I don't use the JDBC connector often. The only time I did, I included a `mode` configuration, though... It would help if you provided your database scripts and sample data as part of a [mcve], though